# Gluon Mobile charm-common-4.2.0.jar not found?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I need help with the charm plugin for scenebuilder 8.2.0/8.3.0 (any version from the two) , which is used to access the fxml files and design them.

I imported the plugin but there is no a single component of it. 
Also the link on the official site does not work, It is displaying 404 error when I try to download it.

One more thing is that I had imported the charm-glisten jar from the scenebuider repository, but View is not there, what is the reason for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to look at the [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). As it stands your post does not make much sense, as it does not contain all the relevant information.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the Scenic Builder version you are using? Also can you add the link you tried and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the version stated by gluon-mobile in the tutorial or documentation is not present on the site either so it is better to use a lower version and work with it.

the charm pludin 4.2.0 is not available using  charm 3.x will work the same.